# Add more filters in timeline of a SO post

Tags: feature-request, timeline

In a question's or answer's timeline, the user has the ability to hide or show vote summaries. But since this activity page shows comments, the question, votes for >1k users, edits, and answers, I think it would be a nice feature for those interested to be able to filter by these types of activity.

I propose filters with an interface similar to other filtering UIs on SO, allowing a user to only see the

- Comments
- Answers
- Edits
- Votes

And possibly later on, allow the user to see a combination of the above.

[image: A Stack Overflow Post's Timeline]

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#post-timeline-filters

Comment: @Shog9 of course there should be a userscript.